# Is a canonical map into the second dual space open?

Tags: topological-vector-spaces

Let $E$ be a topological vector space. Then, consider the second dual space $E^{**}$ with a strong topology and let the canonical map $π:E→E^{**}$ be injective. Then prove that the inverse of $π$ is a continuous map from $π(E)$ to $E$.

This problem is given with the following hint.

> “Show that the topology induced by the inverse of $π$ is stronger than the original topology of $E$.”

I understand it is sufficient to show that the hint but I don’t know how to show the hint. Please give me an answer.

Comment: To clarify, what do you mean by "strong topology" on $E^{**}$?

Comment: A strong topology means a polar topology.